# Set of continuous functions as a ring

Tags: ring-theory

In Artin there is a question to test whether the set is a ring or not - 
$S$ = {Set of all real valued continuous functions}

```
(f+g)(x) = f(x)+g(x)
```

And

```
(f.g)(x) = f(g(x))
```

I have proved this as a ring -

- $S$ is closed under Addition and Multiplication(which is composition in this case)
- Additive inverse is in $S$
- Additive identity $a(x)=0$ is in $S$
- Multiplicative identity is identity map $a(x) = x$ is in $S$

Please correct me if there is something wrong?

Comment: What codomain have the functions? How about distributivity? It would be a ring if the codomain is a ring itself and $(f.g)(x)=f(x).g(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are checking whether it is a subring. However, ask yourself first, subring of what? If you have a ring $R$ and a subsets $S$ of it, you can easily check if $S$ is a subring just by checking a few things. But to prove that something is a ring without happily seeing it as a subset of some ring with the same operations, you have to check *all* the ring axioms. Remember that the addition and multiplication in a ring have to be compatible. Does that hold in your case above?

Comment: yeah sorry just missed that distributive law and the distributive law doesn't hold in this case. So it is not a ring although rest all properties are satisfied.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=1$.

Then $f(g(x)+g(x))=4$ but $f(g(x))+f(g(x))=2$.

So this is not distributive.